# Grouping by duplicate columns to merge them into one column with the same name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine duplicate columns in my dataframe. My dataframe is Multiindexed and looks like

```
                   sex_COPYL    sex_COPYR    age_COPYL    age_COPYR
ID    Date
 A    2010-01-01        NaN           F            NaN          230
 B    2010-01-01        NaN           F            NaN          487
      2010-02-01        NaN           M            NaN          488
 C    2010-01-01        NaN           M            NaN          534
 D    2012-09-08          M         NaN            432          NaN
```

I expect the dataframe to look like

```
                       sex           age
ID    Date
 A    2010-01-01        F            230
 B    2010-01-01        F            487
      2010-02-01        M            488
 C    2010-01-01        M            534
 D    2012-09-08        M            432
```

I'm trying to achieve this by

```
df.groupby(df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('_COPY')[0], 1)).apply(lambda x: x.mode(1)[0])
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Other posts with regards to that error show that the user didn't have the column they were trying to group by. Is my error a result of the duplicate stripped names and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: What prevents you from just deleting the column? I'm assuming the column wouldn't necessarily be all `nan`. Would there be conflicting data? Such as `M` in one column and `F` in the other? Or different ages? How should this be resolved? Or is it always one value and an `nan`?

Comment: @busybear That's a good point, and that assumption is correct. There is always one value and a `nan`. I'll edit my question to reflect that, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Hi nebula, print(df.columns) is of class "<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>". so if you use df.groupby(df.columns) it will throw error as you pointed out above. you have to use df.groupby(list(df.columns)) inorder to work.

Comment: Hi @BhanuTez, but I'm not grouping by the full names of the columns, I'm grouping by `df.columns.map(...)`, which is like grouping by `['sex', 'sex', 'age', 'age']`.

Comment: @HS-nebula I am talking, the reason for "valueError". But anyways your code has column name issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing axis=1 in the groupby:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('_COPY')[0], 1), axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.mode(1)[0])
```

alternative solution (without groupby, but similar with stack and unstack):

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_COPY')[0]).stack().unstack()
```

the stack method drop na values by default

Comment: Thanks, I realized I had a typo in my groupby line, so there shouldn't be a `1` in my `map` code. Also, good alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution:

```
# use both bfill and ffill to handle NaNs on both
# left and right of valid values
df['sex'] = (df.filter(like='sex')
               .bfill(axis=1)
               .ffill(axis=1)
               .iloc[:, 0])

df['age'] = (df.filter(like='age')
               .bfill(axis=1)
               .ffill(axis=1)
               .iloc[:, 0]
               .astype(int))

df = df[['sex', 'age']]
df
                      sex  age
ID         Date
A          2010-01-01   F  230
B          2010-01-01   F  487
           2010-02-01   M  488
C          2010-01-01   M  534
D          2012-09-08   M  432
```

Comment: Thanks, this method works but it doesn't explain why the `groupby` was failing to accomplish the same thing without having to create additional columns.

Comment: As a bonus, I could do this in one line like `df.bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, ::2]` and then rename the columns.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the column names first:

```
df.columns = [c.split('_COPY')[0] for c in df.columns]
df

Out:
    sex sex age age
ID  Date                
A   2010-01-01  NaN F   NaN 230
B   2010-01-01  NaN F   NaN 487
NaN 2010-02-01  NaN M   NaN 488
C   2010-01-01  NaN M   NaN 534
D   2012-09-08  NaN M   NaN 432
```

Then group by column names and use mode:

```
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).agg(lambda x: x.mode(axis=1)[0])

Out:
        age sex
ID  Date        
A   2010-01-01  230.0   F
B   2010-01-01  487.0   F
NaN 2010-02-01  488.0   M
C   2010-01-01  534.0   M
D   2012-09-08  432.0   M
```

**Update**: the original one-liner also works with `axis=1` added to the list of `groupby` parameters (since we're grouping by columns instead of rows):

```
df.groupby(df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('_COPY')[0], 1), axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.mode(1)[0])
```

Comment: So all I needed to do was add the `level=0` to my `groupby`? Can you explain why?

Comment: The problem seems to be with your statement missing `axis=1` (since we need to group by columns instead of rows) as a groupby parameter. The following works well: `df.groupby(df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('_COPY')[0], 1), axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.mode(1)[0])`